# Galois extensions inside a division ring

Tags: galois-theory, fields, division-rings

Let $D$ be a division ring which has finite dimension over its centre.

**Q1.** Under which conditions can one find a maximal subfield $K$ of $D$ and a proper subfield $L$ of $K$ such that $K/L$ is Galois?

**Q2.** Is it possible that such an $L$ does not exist ?

These questions are motivated by Dickson's construction of cyclic algebra, constructing central simple algebra starting from any cyclic Galois extension. I am looking for a kind of converse of this construction, wondering to what extent a simple central algebra (particularly a division ring finite dimensional over its centre) is built up with a cyclic Galois extension.

**Edit.** Thanks to LSpice's comments, the questions reduces to:

> **Q3**. Under which conditions can one find a maximal subfield $L\subset D$ whose normalizer in $D$ properly contains $L$ ?

Comment: You can set $L$ equal to $K$.

Comment: @JasonStarr ;-) Edited accordingly !

Comment: Is **Q1** to be answered *after* the field $K$ has been specified, or is the question whether there is *some* maximal subfield $K$ of $D$ that is Galois over some subfield $L$?  Must the subfield $L$ contain the centre of $D$?

Comment: @LSpice I edited the question : $K$ is not specified (I thought that the maximal sufields of $D$ are conjugated, is that false ?) $L$ need not contain the centre of $D$, but I'd rather it does.

Comment: It is false that the maximal subfields are conjugate.  For example, a quaternionic division algebra over $\mathbb Q_p$ (let's say $p \ne 2$, although it probably doesn't matter) contains all quadratic extensions of $\mathbb Q_p$, in particular a ramified and the unramified such extension, and no extension of degree bigger than 2.

Comment: @LSpice: $Aut(D/Z(D))$ is never trivial, consider conjugation by any non-central element. How would you proceed then ?

Comment: I deleted the incorrect comment before seeing your reply to it; sorry!  A positive answer to **Q1** would certainly be implied by, and I suspect (by something like Skolem–Noether) is equivalent to (if we require that $L$ contain $Z(D)$), the existence of a maximal subfield $K$ and an element $x$ in $D$ normalising, but not belonging to, $K$—since, in that case, we could just take $L$ to be the fixed-point set of $x$ on $K$.  However, I don't know whether such a pair $(K, x)$ always exists.

Comment: One more silly comment: suppose one can always (*i.e.*, for any division algebra that is finite-dimensional over its centre) exhibit a subfield $K'$ (not necessarily maximal) such that $\mathrm N_{D^\times}(K') \ne \mathrm C_{D^\times}(K')$.  If $K'$ is not maximal, then we may replace $D$ by $C_D(K')$, and so reason by downward induction on the dimension of $D$ over its centre.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is relevant to answer more than a year after the question was raised, especially because I'm not really fully answering the question.

First, I would like to point out that an answer to the question would give a positive answer to the very hard and still open following question: let $p$ be a prime number, and let $F$ be a field of characteristic different from $p$. Is any central division $F$-algebra of degree $p$ cyclic (i.e. does it has a cyclic maximal subfield)? This is known for $p=2,3$...and that's it.
No one knows what is the correct answer even for $p=5.$

Now assume that $D$ is a division ring with center $F$, which is of  degree $p$ over $F.$ Any maximal subfield $L$ containing $F$ has degree $p$, so the only proper subfield of $L$ is $F$. Asking if one can choose $L/F$ to be Galois is then equivalent to ask whether $L/F$ can be chosen to be cyclic, which is exactly the statement of the previous question.

On the positive side, one can show that if $D$ is a central division $F$-algebra of degree $p^m$ ($p$ prime), then the answer is "yes" up to a prime-to-$p$ extension, if $F$ has not characteristic $p$:

By a well-known theorem of Albert, one can find a prime-to-$p$ extension $E/F$ such that $D\otimes_F E$ (which is still division) contains a maximal subfield $L/E$ such that there is a filtration  $F=L_0\subset L_1\subset\cdots \subset L_{r-1}\subset L_r=L$, where each $L_i/L_{i-1}$ has degree $p$. Now $E(\zeta_p)/E$ is prime to $p$, so replacing $E$ by $E(\zeta_p)$, one may assume that $E$ contains $\zeta_p$. In this case , $L/L_{r-1}$ is a cyclic Kummer extension.

To finish with this long message, I just don't understand why @Drike wants a Galois extension "from the above". Even if the answer to the question is "yes", I don't see what interesting result it could imply on the structure of central division algebras. From my point of view, the structure of subfields of division algebras are more interesting. 
Just to remind the potential future readers of this text: a central division $F$-algebra does not always contain a Galois maximal subfield (there are counter examples in degree $8$).